# Electron capture mouse events when window is not focused

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, mouseevent

Is there a way to capture mouse events like hover and click even when Electron window is not focused? So that my buttons' hover/click effects still work?

Right now, I need to first switch to the Electron window either by clicking or alt-tabbing for the mouse events to be captured.

I'm fairly new to js and electron and I can't seem to find anything on this. But since it works with Atom editor, I'm assuming its possible?

Do I need additional module like mentioned in this post for capturing keyboard events: [Atom Electron capture all keyboard events even when app is unfocused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391983/atom-electron-capture-all-keyboard-events-even-when-app-is-unfocused)?

Thanks! Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When creating a new Electron window using `new BrowserWindow`, it is possible to have mouse click events captured even when the window is not focused by adding:

```
acceptFirstMouse: true
```

to the [BrowserWindow options](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions).

As for capturing mouse hover events, I'm afraid this is not possible *out of the box*.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I'm guessing for hovering I may need to capture global mouse events and focus the window somehow?

Comment: This is only for Mac.

Comment: And for Linux and Windows?